# Thread not terminating correctly, I think

Tags: android, java-threads

```
public String newUser = "false";
public double lat = 0.0, lon = 0.0;
```

I have the following function in my android app (called when a Button is clicked) which starts a thread:

```
public void SignUpFunction(View view) {
    assignValues();
    String filledAll = checkIfFilled();
    if (filledAll.equals("true")) {
    Log.d("LIFECYCLE", "calling thread..");

    //my thread
    new validateThread().start();

    Log.d("After thread start","This log call does not occur");

    if (newUser.equals("true")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait as we obtain your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getMyLocationFunction();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

validateThread:

```
class validateThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("LIFECYCLE", "validateThread entered...");
        try {
                        newUser = "true";
                        Log.d("validateThread", "Validated and found new user");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("validateThread", "Exception in validateThread: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The thread runs correctly...but after the last line, it does not go back to its point of start. I don't understand why this is happening because I've used threads before and they all work correctly.

I know I can just give the getMyLocation function inside the thread but I really need it this way.

I've searched for similar questions but none helped.. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not go back to its point of start"? are you expecting `if (newUser.equals("true"))` to be `true` because you're setting it as such in the thread?

Comment: Threads run in parallel together. 
You might want switch
`if(newUser.equals("true"))`
to 
`do{
    ...
} while(!newUser.equals("true"))`

Comment: actually I've not posted the entire content here.. No matter what statement I give there (even a 'Log' statement instead of 'if') does not get executed..

Comment: you are doing the wrong assumption that the UI Thread is waiting validateThread to finish before continuing its execution flow

Comment: Not really.. I edited my question.. Even the log call that I give after starting the thread doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

It's a race. SignUpFunction should wait until validateThread decides whether or not to set newUser = "true". Even with the race your code may work sometimes, but that is by accident.

Comment: If that was the case, if I gave a Log statement after starting the thread, it should've worked right.. But that doesn't happen either..

Comment: Maybe log.d threw an exception. Note: this is not an answer, because you did not really ask a question. General comment is, remove code from your program until something works, then start adding code back until you observe the effect you first described. Then remove irrelevant code until what remains consisely exhibits the issue. I would suggest converting all your log... lines to println or equivalent. During this process you will most probably already have found your issue. If not, then edit your question.